# Checking presence of element in regular time interval Selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium framework where I am checking for the completion of load of three heading tags  with id say head1, head2, head3.The total wait time for which I want to wait to ensure the load of all the three heading tags is 12 seconds.The loading of three heading tags can happen either in any time 1,2,3,4... Seconds.

Now I want to do a regular check for every 2 seconds till 12 seconds to check if all three heading tags are loaded so I can jump to other part of code. I have tried few code but unable to figure the exact code which meets my requirement.

The below code contains wait for heading tags to get loaded which checks for h1 tag every 2 seconds till 12 seconds.

**Selenium Code**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://URL.com/Sample.jsp");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                       .withTimeout(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("h1")));

if((driver.findElement(By.id("h1")).getText()).length() >0)
   System.out.println("Element Loaded");
else
   System.out.println("Element yet to be Loaded");
```

**Html Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

myFunction();

function myFunction()
{
    setTimeout(function(){populateDiv1();},3000);
    setTimeout(function(){populateDiv2();},6000);
    setTimeout(function(){populateDiv3();},9000);
}

function populateDiv1()
{   
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<h1 id='head1'>Div1 Loaded</h1>";        
}

function populateDiv2()
{
  document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = "<h1 id='head2'>Div2 Loaded</h1>";        
}

function populateDiv3()
{
  document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML = "<h1 id='head3'>Div3 Loaded</h1>";        
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, took me a while to find a solution but I thing this one should work for your case

```
ExpectedCondition e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id*='div']")).size() >= 2;
    }
};

WebDriverWait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                   .withTimeout(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(e);
```

You can of course cange the condition to anything you want, like finding each element separately, you just need to return a `boolean`. This how you can create your own `ExpectedConditions` in order to customize Seleniums behavior.

Comment: Thanks for Reply.The only thing which I am not clear is div[id*='div'].Could you kindly explain whats happening.Thank u once again

Comment: This will select all elements which id contains string `div` (so like in your example, `div1`, `div2`, etc...)